# Defining Free Bind in a way that is compatible with the Free Monad

Tags: haskell, category-theory, free-monad

So we have the free monad: (encoding may vary, but they're all the same)

```
data Free f a = Pure a
              | Impure (f (Free f a))

instance Functor f => Monad (Free f) where
    pure = Pure
    Pure   x >>= f = f x
    Impure x >>= f = Impure ((>>= f) <$> x)

liftFree :: Functor f => f a -> Free f a
liftFree x = Impure (Pure <$> x)

runFree :: Monad g => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> Free f a -> g a
runFree _ (Pure   x) = pure x
runFree f (Impure x) = join (runFree f <$> f x)
```

such that `runFree` forms a monad homomorphism, which is the defining property of the free monad.

```
runFree f (pure x) = pure x
runFree f (liftFree x >>= liftFree . g) = f x >>= (f . g)
-- + some other associativity requirements
```

We can also make a similar construction to (what I believe to be) the free [`Bind` from semigroupoids](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.3.2/docs/Data-Functor-Bind.html), which is a functor with only bind `>>-`:

```
data Free1 f a = Done (f a)
               | More (f (Free1 f a))

instance Functor f => Bind (Free f) where
    Done x >>- f = More (f <$> x)
    More x >>- f = More ((>>- f) <$> x)

liftFree1 :: f a -> Free1 f a
liftFree1 = Done

runFree1 :: Bind g => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> Free1 f a -> g a
runFree1 f (Done x) = f x
runFree1 f (More x) = f x >>- runFree1 f
```

and we get the appropriate bind homomorphism:

such that `runFree1` forms a bind homomorphism, which is the defining property:

```
runFree1 f (liftFree1 x >>- liftFree1 . g) = f x >>- (f . g)
-- + some associativity laws
```

Now, these two types are great.  We can convert from `Free1` to `Free`, which makes sense:

```
toFree :: Free1 f a -> Free f a
toFree (Done x) = Impure (Pure   <$> x)
toFree (More x) = Impure (toFree <$> x)
```

but converting backwards is trickier.  To go from a `Free` to a `Free1`, we would have to handle two cases:

1. The `Free` is pure, so cannot be represented in `Free1`.
2. The `Free` is impure, so can be represented in `Free1`.

It makes sense that these two cases can be handled statically, since we can just match on `Pure` or `Impure`.

So a reasonable type signature might be:

```
fromFree :: Functor f => Free f a -> Either a (Free1 f a)
```

but I am having problems writing this.

```
fromFree :: Free f a -> Either a (Free1 f a)
fromFree (Pure   x) = Left x   -- easy
fromFree (Impure x) = Right ?? -- a bit harder
```

It looks like the main problem is that we need to decide whether or not to use the `Done` or the `More` constructor without ever "running" the f.  We need a:

```
f (Free f a) -> Free1 f a
```

which sounds like it might be troublesome for functors were you can't "get out", like `IO`.

So, this sounds impossible, unless I'm missing something.

There's another encoding that I've tried:

```
data Free1 f a = Free1 (f (Free f a))
```

this *does* lets us define `fromFree`, and it borrows from the `NonEmpty` construction (`data NonEmpty a = a :| [a]`).  And I was able to use this approach when defining the "free `Apply`", which was nice.  This does let us write `toFree`, `fromFree`, `liftFree1`, and a `Bind` instances.  However, I can't seem to write `runFree1`:

```
runFree1 :: Bind g => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> f (Free f a) -> g a
```

as soon as I do anything, I seem to require `return :: a -> g a`, but we don't have this for all `Bind g` (I found a possible version that typechecks, but it performs the effects twice and so is not a proper bind homomorphism)

So, while this method gives us `fromFree`, I can't seem to find a way to write `runFree1`, which is the very thing that gives it "free `Bind`" capabilities.

Of these two methods, either we:

1. Have an actual free `Bind` with `runFree1`, but it is imcompatible with `Free` in that you can't "match" a `Free` into either a `Free1`, or a pure value.
2. Have a type that is compatible with `Free` (maybe a "nonempty `Free`"), but is not actually a free `Bind` (no `runFree1`), and defeats the whole purpose.

From this I can make one of two conclusions:

1. There is some way to make a free Bind `Free1` that is compatible with `Free`, but I have not been able to figure it out yet
2. Fundamentally, we cannot have a free `Bind` that is compatible with `Free`.  This seems to contradict my intuition (we can always immediately decide if a `Free` is pure or impure, so we should also be able to immediately distinguish between pure (zero effects) or `Free1`), but maybe there is a deeper reason that I am missing out on?

Which of these is the case?  If #1, what is way, and if #2, what is the deeper reason? :)

Thank you in advance!

---

**Edit** To dispel my uncertainty about whether or not I was working with a "true Free Bind", I started looking at one that was truly a Free Bind by definition:

```
newtype Free1 f a = Free1 { runFree1 :: forall g. Bind g => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> g a }
```

And I can't seem to be able to write `fromFree` for this one, either.  In the end I seem to need a `g (Either a (Free1 a)) -> g a`.

If I can't write `fromFree` for this, then it stands to reason that I can't write `fromFree` for any implementation of the free bind, since all implementations are isomorphic to this one.

Is there a way to write `fromFree` for this one, even?  Or is it all impossible :'(  It all worked so well for `Alt`/`Plus` and `Apply`/`Applicative`.

Comment: This doesn't seem possible at all. Conider `Free (Integer ->)` and `Free1 (Integer ->)`.

Comment: @n.m. do you think that is a limitation of this particular encoding of `Free1`, or of all "free `Bind`" implementations in general? (which would imply that my `Free1` is not a proper free Bind)

Comment: Hmm I don't really know...

Comment: I tried playing around with the "final form" of the Free Bind, which I am sure 100% is the actual Free Bind (`type FreeBind f a = forall g. Bind g => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> g a`) and satisfies all the free bind laws.

In this version I cannot implement `fromFree` either, so it might be the case that this is true for all Free Binds.

Comment: If it is true that there the free bind is fundamentally incompatible with the free monad, I'm now curious to see why this is the case for `Bind` and `Monad`, but not for `Apply` and `Applicative`, or `Alt` and `Plus`.  Both of these can be properly converted, but not `Bind` and `Monad`.

Comment: I'm now wondering about the `Apply` case. Shouldn't we run into the same problem when it comes to squeezing `Pure` into `data Ap1 f a = Lift (f a) | forall x. Ap (f x) (Ap f (x -> a))`? (Or did I mess up my free apply?)

Comment: @duplode my Free Apply was `data Ap1 f a = forall x. Ap1 (f x) (Ap f (x -> a))` :)

Comment: @JustinL. (1) Oops, there was a typo in my `Ap1` above: I meant `data Ap1 f a = Lift (f a) | forall x. Ap1 (f x) (Ap1 f (x -> a))`, as I didn't actually use the free applicative `Ap` (In any case, it seems our types are equivalent). (2) I might be missing something, but I still don't see how we might have the `a -> Ap1 f a` injection needed for handling `Pure`, even with your `Ap1` -- the closest thing seems to be `\a -> Ap1 u (Pure (const a))`, but in that case I don't know where to get an `u :: f x` from.

Comment: @duplode i've written the implementations of the analogous functions here https://github.com/mstksg/functor-combinators/blob/88b1edba8bb30acd37d9b30c0ff63fd9f8725581/src/Data/Functor/Apply/Free.hs#L80-L83 :)

Comment: @JustinL. Thanks! Nevermind my objections -- I had lost track of your actual problem statement for a moment there :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `Free f a` is the type of trees with "`f`-nodes" and `a`-leaves, the "free Bind-structure" `Free1 f a` is the type of such trees with an additional restriction: the children of an `f`-node are either all leaves or all `f`-nodes. Thus if we consider binary trees:

```
data Bin x = Bin x x
```

Then `Free Bin a` contains the following tree shape, but `Free1 Bin a` does not:

```
Impure (Bin
  (Pure a)
  (Impure (Bin (Pure a) (Pure a))))
```

because the root node has one leaf and one `Bin` node as children, while a `Free1 Bin a` should have either two leaves, or two `Bin` nodes. Such a pattern could occur deep in a `Free` tree, so even a partial conversion `Free f a -> Maybe (Free1 f a)` is not possible with only a `Functor f` constraint. A `Traversable f` constraint with an assumption that the traversals are finite makes that conversion possible, but of course it's still not practical for large trees since they must be fully traversed before any output can be produced.

Note that because of the above characterization of `Free1`, this other definition in terms of `Free` is not actually equivalent:

```
data Free1 f a = Free1 (f (Free f a))  -- Not a free Bind
```

Comment: Ah.  This seems to be the fundamental difference -- "all leaves, or all nodes".  it's interesting that `Bind` gives rise to such a restriction.

This makes sense to me, thank you! :)